# ASP.NET MVC3: Razor view crashes without error?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've been having problems with the view ending the response early. There are no server errors, or even an error when debugging the app.

Whenever it happens, refresh will always render the correct output.

Desired output (illustration)

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <my view>
            <content 1 />
            <content 2 />
            <content 3 />
        </my view>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I get (illustration)

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <my view> </my view>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seams that you are getting only the `_Layout.cshtml` and not the actual View, can you go back and check the entire `Route` path, plus if you are using `RenderBody()` in the correct part... best test is add `@{ Layout = null; }` in your `View` and run it, this will not include any Layout and you will see only the View code.

Comment: It's more of a bug than a consisten issue. It only happens from time to time. (F5 will always render it correctly)
Sometimes I get " " where RenderBody() was, but I have also gotten some of the content like half of the result.

PS: I'm thinking it might be a problem with Chrome. I haven't been able to reproduce the problem in any other browser yet.